# AJAX not returning result from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to learn from an example from online,for a login form with php and jquery and i am using the exactly the same example, but for some reason the AJAX isnt getting anything back but redirecting my to another php. 
Here is a link of what i had been trying and the problem.

http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/testlogin.html

It supposed to get the result and display it back on the same page, but it is redirecting me to another blank php with the result on it. 
Thanks for your time, i provided all the codes that i have, i hope the question isnt too stupid.

**HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id= "loginform" class="form-horizontal" action='http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/agentlogin.php' method='POST'>
            <p id="result"></p>
            <!-- Sign In Form -->
            <input required="" id="userid" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Registered Email" class="input-medium" required="">
            <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-medium">
            <!-- Button -->
            <button id="signinbutton" name="signin" class="btn btn-success"  style="width:100px;">Sign In</button>
        </form>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javasript" src="http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("button#signinbutton").click(function() {
    if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "") {
        $("p#result).html("Please enter both userna");
    } else {
        $.post($("#loginform").attr("action"), $("#loginform:input").serializeArray(), function(data) {
            $("p#result").html(data);
        });
        $("#loginform").submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

**php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
//get form data
$username = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
$password = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
if (!$username || !$password) {
    $no = "Please enter name and password";
    echo ($no);
} else {
    //log in
    $login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Agent WHERE username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($login) == 0)
        echo "No such user";
    else {
        while ($login_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login)) {

            //get database password
            $password_db = $login_row['password'];

            //encrypt form password
            $password1 = md5($password1);

            //check password
            if ($password1 != $password_db)
                echo "Incorrect Password";
            else {
                //assign session
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password1;
                header("Location: http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/aboutus.html");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Edit

```
$("button#signinbutton").click(function(){

    if($("#username").val() ==""||$("#password").val()=="")
$("p#result).html("Please enter both userna");
  else


    $.post ($("#loginform").attr("action"),
        $("#loginform:input").serializeArray(),
    function(data)  {
$("p#result).html(data);  });  




});
 $("#loginform").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi,

I don't see where you use Ajax ... for use ajax in jQuery it's $.ajax.

Comment: @Kvasir $.post is also jquery ajax

Comment: @Clarklight Maybe you should remove the output buffering? `ob_start();`

Comment: I tried that too, its same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are being redirected is that you are also calling $.submit. The classic form submit will redirect you to a new page, which is exactly what you don't want when you're using AJAX. If you remove this call:

```
$("#loginform").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

you probably should have working solution. If not, let me know :)

Comment: I just tried it but its still doing the same thing, i pasted what i tried in the edit above

Comment: Agree with @Khusboo, remove the header in your PHP

Comment: I removed it but its still doing the same thing

Comment: Another thing to remove. Remove the following from your HTML: `<form id= "loginform" class="form-horizontal" action='http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/agentlogin.php' method='POST'>` You are mixing normal submit with AJAX. Your form should look like this: `<form id= "loginform" class="form-horizontal" >`

Comment: I removed that line, and pasted what you gave me, it is not redirecting me now! But it isnt displaying anything tho, because i have 2 echos in the php. Shouldnt it echo it on my html?

Comment: It should, you could perhaps console.log it instead of directly setting your HTML to be sure. Also, in your question you have this line: `$("p#result).html(data);  });` which is missing a closing " after `p#result` though this may be a typo in your question :)

Comment: em... thats not the problem i added the " back its still not displaying it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56633/discussion-between-danielvdende-and-clarklight).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Remove :-

```
header("Location: http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/aboutus.html");
```

and if you want to display the data, echo username and password.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password1;
echo $username."<br>".;
echo $password1;
```

Comment: I tried that it is not displaying anything back on my html still

Comment: alert(data) in your code and tell us what is coming there

Comment: I tried that and looked in the console, its blank there

Comment: Is anything coming in your variables? Please check

Comment: i tried echo"hello";at the top of the php and in console its still blank

Comment: in console, what is the value of posts? Is it going to correct php page ?

Comment: You can give it a try http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/testlogin.html i uploaded to a remote server. In console there are absolutely nothing, and it just refresh the page when i click the button.

Comment: @Clarklight `<script type="text/javasript"` has a spelling mistake. Please correct that

Comment: Why it is taking values in url ?

Comment: I can get it to return the echo"hello" but it deosnt seem to be submitting the username and password cos i am having Notice: Undefined index: username

Comment: @Clarklight, you have the syntax error here `$("p#result").html("Please enter both userna")`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i fixed the problem, i removed the input from ("#loginform:input")

Answer (score 0):

Modify your javascript section so that

```
$("button#signinbutton").click(function() {
    if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "") {
        $("p#result).html("Please enter both userna");
    } else {
        $.post($("#loginform").attr("action"), $("#loginform:input").serializeArray(), function(data) {
            $("p#result").html(data);
        });
    }
});

$("#loginform").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

is outside the function call.

Comment: I just tried it with what i put in the edit. It is still doing the same thing tho

Comment: @Clarklight Try as above and remove the `header` as suggested in another answer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into mine and saved it and uploaded it but its still doing the same thing